# Selecting a button using its name among buttons that were created dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm creating buttons dynamically. How can I select a specific button using its name (ex: in the following code using "i" ) from remaining part of the code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    button b = new button();
    b.name = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Iterate over all controls, typeof Button with name you specified?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Sorry. I'm just practicing thats why i'm not much serious about naming conventions. And thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution is search the button in the `Controls` collection.

```
Button btn = (Button) this.Controls["nameButton"];
//...DO Something
```

The problem of this solution is that if there isn't a button with the `nameButton` the JIT will throw an exception. If you want prevent this you must insert the code in a `try catch` block or, if you prefer, you can use Sergey Berezovskiy solution(he uses `Linq` and I think it's more clear)

Answer (score 2):

First - its not enough to just create buttons. You need to add them to some control:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Name = String.Format("button{0}", i); // use better names
    // subscribe to Click event otherwise button is useless
    button.Click = Button_Click;
    Controls.Add(button); // add to form's controls
}
```

Now you can search child controls of buttons container for some specific button:

```
var button = Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "button2");
```

NOTE: If you'll use *buttonN* name pattern then make sure you don't have other buttons with same names, because this pattern is used by VS designer.

UPDATE: If you will use same event handler for all dynamic buttons Click event (actually you should), then you can easily get button which raised even in event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // that's the button which was clicked
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    // use it
}
```

Comment: You can also bind the name of the button to the button's command parameter, so that in the event that the buttons all use the same handler, dynamicButton_Click(...) for example, you can find which button was clicked by examining the parameter passed to the handler.

Comment: @MikeofSST yep, agree - event sender is easily can be retrieved in event handler. I'll probably update answer with this info

Answer (score 1):

You have to *place* your button *somewhere*:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Mind the case: Button, not button
    Button b = new Button();
    // // Mind the case: Name, not name
    b.Name = i.ToString();

    //TODO: place your buttons somewhere:
    // on a panel
    //   myPanel.Controls.Add(b);
    // on a form
    //   this.Controls.Add(b);
    // etc.

    //TODO: it seems, that you want to add Click event, something like
    //  b.Click += MyButtonClick;  
  }
```

then you can just query appropriate `Controls` for the `Button`:

```
  Button b = myPanel.Controls["1"] as Button;

  if (b != null) {
    // The Button is found ...
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just put them in a Button[] or you could iterate over the Controls collection of your Form.