# How Can i Change the ComboBox Name by parameter/variable?

Tags: c#, parameters, combobox, rename

I wrote this method so i can use it instead of repeating the code.but how can i change `cmb1` (ComboBox Name) to something like `cmb(i)`. what i mean if i =10 ComboBox name = `cmb10`.for this part of the code(**cmb1**.Items.Add(srd.GetValue(0).ToString());).i want to change the number regarding to i.is it possible?if it is please help me!

This is the method im trying

```cs
public void ComboText(string text,int i)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-V0HE9JH\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Parts_Shop;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@connectionString);

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select manufacturer from Parts where item_type = '" + text + "'", connection);
        SqlDataReader srd = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (srd.Read())
        {
            cmb1.Items.Add(srd.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this solution what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753946/selecting-a-button-using-its-name-among-buttons-that-were-created-dynamically-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Controls` collection has two indexer overloads one accepting an `int` and another a `string` representing the name of the control.

```cs
var cmb = (ComboBox)Controls["cmb" + i];
```

This works if the combo box is placed directly on the form. If it is placed on another control like e.g. a panel, then access this container control's `Controls` property:

```cs
var cmb = (ComboBox)panel1.Controls["cmb" + i];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you meant Windows Forms `ComboBox`. If that is so, you are free to change its `Name` property, but you can't change its in-code name.

If all your comboboxes are already set, possible solution would be to set up the `Name` property beforehand (`cmb1.Name = "1"`, `cmb2.Name = "2"` etc.) and then, in your `void ComboText(string text,int i)` loop through all the comboboxes in the window (e.g like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739672/how-can-i-loop-over-all-comboboxes-controls-i-have-and-add-the-items-of-each-com) or use System.Linq's `FirstOrDefault()` method) and get the one with the `Name == i.ToString()`.